# New Line characters not recognized by Smtp2Go?

Tags: c#, smtp2go

I have a fairly simple method which takes a payload and sends a message to create an email using Smtp2Go.

However, when I have a string such as "Hello World\r\nHow are you?" the email shows everything on a single line.  Is there a way I can handle this?

I'm using Smtp2Go.ApiClient

```
    public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(EmailNotificationEvent notification)
    {
        var message = new EmailMessage(notification.Body, notification.Subject, _smtp2GoSettings.EmailSender,
            notification.Recipients);
        // I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work
        // message.AddCustomHeader("Mime-Type", "text/plain");
        var response = await _smtpService.SendEmail(message);

        if (!response.Data.Failures.Any()) return true;

        foreach (var failure in response.Data.Failures)
            _logger.LogWarning(
                "Smtp2Go failure detected. Error: {error}, ErrorCode: {errorCode} Failure: {failure}",
                response.Data.Error, response.Data.ErrorCode, failure);

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Smtp2Go but if it defaults to HTML format that would be expected. Send `"Hello World<br>How are you?"` to verify this.

Comment: @AlexK. Your suggestion does work, but we're currently getting bodies with either plain text or HTML.

I recently found that they have a BodyText property, but it seems to ignore \r\n as well.